# React read string as component

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, react-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap framework to render a simple 3 column grid layout out of some content on a page. Where it gets complicated, I'm trying to conditionally render bootstrap `<Row>` or `</Row>` depending on where we are in the loop - for instance ,render a `<Row>` if `index % 3 == 0` and render a `</Row>` if `(index + 1) % 3 == 0`. Because there are problems with conditional rendering in map, I've come up with the following approach which would work ***if there was a way to read a string as a React component***. Does anyone know how to do this?

```js
const websiteData = [
  {
    name: "abcdefg",
    url: "https://www.abcedfg.com/",
    categories: ["react"],
    thumbnail: require("./assets/images/image.png"),
  },
  {
    name: "rrrrrr",
    url: "https://www.rrrrrr.com/",
    categories: ["wordpress"],
    thumbnail: require("./assets/images/rrrrrr.png"),
  },
  {
    name: "jjjjjjjj",
    url: "https://www.jjjjjjjj.com/",
    categories: ["wordpress"],
    thumbnail: require("./assets/images/jjjjjjjj.png"),
  },
  {
    name: "ffffff",
    url: "https://www.ffffff.com/",
    categories: ["wordpress"],
    thumbnail: require("./assets/images/ffffff.png"),
  },
  {
    name: "dddddd",
    url: "https://www.dddddd.com/",
    categories: ["wordpress"],
    thumbnail: require("./assets/images/dddddd.png"),
  },
  {
    name: "adadads",
    url: "https://www.adadads.com/",
    categories: ["wordpress"],
    thumbnail: require("./assets/images/adadads.png"),
  },
];
const RowOpen = (props) => {
  const { index } = props;

  if (index % 3 == 0) {
    return "<Row>";
  } else {
    return <span />;
  }
};

const RowClose = (props) => {
  const { index } = props;

  if (index + (1 % 3) == 0) {
    return "</Row>";
  } else {
    return <span />;
  }
};

const Websites = () => {
  return websiteData.map((site, index) => {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <RowOpen index={index} />
        <Col md="4">
          <a>
            <img style={{ maxWidth: "100%" }} src={site.thumbnail} />
          </a>
        </Col>
        <RowClose index={index} />
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  });
};
```

Ultimately I want to loop through `websiteData` and wind up with something like this:

```html
<Row>
<Col md=4">
...

</Col>
<Col md=4">
...

</Col>

<Col md=4">
...

</Col>

</Row>
<Row>
<Col md=4">
...

</Col>

<Col md=4">
...

</Col>

<Col md=4">
...
</Col>

</Row>
```

Comment: What you really want to do ? Have not you got the solution what you wanted ?

Comment: Why not something like.... `const RowDisplay = props => { return (<Row>{rowinfo}</Row>); }`?

Comment: @Muzamilijaz see edit where I made clear final desired result

Answer (score 1):

You have `<RowOpen index={index} />...<RowClose index={index} />`, and then these are defined as returning `"<Row>"` and `"</Row>"`.  To be clear, these are strings, and will display as plain text, and not as components.  You cannot define components like this in ReactJS.  You must define them like so...

```
var component = <Row />;
```

Just try it with your approach in an a [sandbox online](https://codesandbox.io/s/y2lrywpk21):

> Expected corresponding JSX closing tag for

Do this instead: Make a display function for each row...

```
const Websites = () => {
  return (
    websiteData.map((site, index) => {
      return (
        <React.Fragment>
            {RowDisplay(site, index)}
        </React.Fragment>
      )
    })
  )
}
```

And then have your `RowDisplay()` function display either either `<Row>`'s or `<span>`'s...

```
const RowDisplay = (site, index) => {
  if (index + 1 % 3 == 0) {
    return RowDisplayRow(site, index);
  } else {
    return RowDisplaySpan(site, index);
  }
}
```

Then you just need the final Row/Span display functions...

```
  const RowDisplayRow = (site, index) => {
    return (
            <Row index={index}>
            <Col md="4">
              <a>
                <img style={{ maxWidth: '100%' }} src={site.thumbnail} />
              </a>
            </Col>
            </Row index={index}>
    );
  }
  
  const RowDisplaySpan = (site, index) => {
    return (
            <Row index={index}>
            <Col md="4">
              <a>
                <img style={{ maxWidth: '100%' }} src={site.thumbnail} />
              </a>
            </Col>
            </Row index={index}>
    );
  }
```

I have done this all in sudo-code, but, I think you'll probably get the idea I'm trying to demonstrate.  *Explanation is sometimes much more important than just code!*

Comment: Thanks, the problem here is that I need 3 <Col> inside each <Row>.

Comment: @DLateef: Sure, this part `if (index + 1 % 3 == 0) {` is still in the code.  But if you just need `<Row><Col/><Col/><Col/></Row>`, why not just code it that way?

Comment: The main reason I posted was to explain the problem in the title, "read string as component," and I tried to make a future-proof answer.  The needs of development are always evolving and changing, understandable!  But did my answer help you understand react strings vs components?  That was my main hope!

Comment: thanks I do appreciate it. I understand the difference between react strings and components. My hope was that there is someway to read a string as a component name, the same way, for instance, that ```eval()``` can be used to read a string as a variable. Anyways, I see how you handled the iteration now and I'm going to try and let you know!

Answer (score 0):

You just simply put the conditions in the map like

```
   return (
      websiteData.map((site, index) => {
        return (
          <React.Fragment>
            {index % 3 == 0 ? <Row /> : <span />}
            <Col md="4">
              <a>
                <img style={{ maxWidth: '100%' }} src={site.thumbnail} />
              </a>
            </Col>
           {index + 1 % 3 == 0 ? </Row> : <span /> }
          </React.Fragment>
        )
      })
    )
```

Try this You will get your desired output ! It will help
Simple and best approach ! :)

Comment: That won't work unfortunately, can't have a self-closing  <Row/>. Also react won't allow to render a </Row>  by itself in condition with a corresponding opening tag.

Comment: what does rendering ```</Row>``` meant for. Whats it?

Comment: React wont allow opening and closing tags in separate conditionals